# How to use REST API PATCH command with Google Apps Script UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script, firebase, urlfetch, x-http-method-override

I am trying to PATCH (partially update) Firebase records (firebase.com). This works perfect outside of Google Apps Script using PATCH. GAS is not supporting PATCH and I tried X-HTTP-Method-Override without success. Using GAS with X-HTTP-Method-Override renders the same result as a standard GET. There is no security on my test database. No log-in is required.

var myPayload = "{\"WSD124\" : {\"auction\" : {\"stockno\" : \"ESD124\", \"highbid\" : \"240\"}}}";

var myURL = "https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/auctions/.json";

var options = {
    headers: {
      "X-HTTP-Method-Override" : "PATCH"
    },
    method: "POST",
    payload: myPayload
};

var oResponse =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(myURL,options);

Answer (score 3):

A quick update for those coming back to this old thread - we now support X-HTTP-Method-Override headers on all REST API calls, so this should now work

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

This is now supported. See Chris Raynor's answer.

**OLD ANSWER**

We don't currently support X-HTTP-Method-Override though we are considering it.  For now you'll likely have to do a PUT with the whole record.  Give us an email at support@firebase.com if this is significantly blocking you.